# Pulling data from Teradata using Python - specifically how to 'chunk' data so that hardware resources are not overrun

Tags: python, pandas, teradata, vertica, chunks

and thank you in advance for any ideas/suggestions/solutions. I have basic knowledge of Python, so if I am misstating something, or missing something please let me know. I am absolutely trying to learn as I go.

So, onto my issue: Have a DB that I don't own (but have read access to) with data I need to pull into my DB for further parsing/joining/etc. Source DB is Teradata, destination DB is Vertica. I have the below script up and running, however the full pull is multiple 10s of millions of rows. I can return 1M rows no problem, so what I want to do is to 'chunk' the data into 1M rows of data, append to my destination DB table, and continue on until all data from the source table has been consumed. Thoughts?

```
# Import libraries
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
import sqlalchemy as sa


server_name = 'HostServerName'
domain_user = 'DomainAccount'
domain_password = 'DomainAccountPassword'
login_mechanism = 'LDAP'

Host3 = 'VerticaServerName'
UserName3 = 'VerticaUser'
Password3 = 'VerticaUserPassword'
Database3 = 'VerticaUserDB'

# Query against DB
query1 = 
'SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 FROM HostServerName.Table1 WHERE Column3 IS NOT NULL'

#Connect to the HostServerName/Teradata DB and pull data
with teradatasql.connect(
  host=server_name, user=domain_user
, password=domain_password
, logmech=login_mechanism
, encryptdata='true'
) as connect:
 data = pd.read_sql(query1, connect
)
print(data)

# update the dataframe type, converts 'text'/string values to varchar
def updateType(data_para):
    dtypedict = {}  # create and empty dictionary
    for i,j in zip(data.columns,data.dtypes):
        if "object" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sa.types.VARCHAR})

    return dtypedict
updatedict = updateType(data)

#Connect to the Vertica DB and append data to table
engine = create_engine(f'vertica+vertica_python://{UserName3}
      :{Password3}@{Host3}/{Database3}'
     , pool_pre_ping=True, poolclass=NullPool
)
data.to_sql(
  'VerticaUSERDB.Table2'
, engine
, schema='VerticaSchema'
, if_exists='append'
, dtype=updatedict
, index=False
)
```

I did try to do this using some other answers on stackoverflow, however it errored out and I don't understand the errors I received.

Comment: [`read_sql_query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) has a `chunksize` parameter that may be helpful.

Comment: So - this is something I did try before ("data = pd.read_sql(query1, connect, chunksize=1000000)")

Traceback (most recent call last): "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\SubscriberDataPulls\Teradatahostscript.py", line 34, in updateType
    for i,j in zip(data.columns,data.dtypes):
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'columns'
<generator object SQLiteDatabase._query_iterator at 0x000001C67B0AECE0>

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I am not understanding that error?

Comment: I think the error happens to be related to the operation where I am dumping the data into a blank dictionary and converting/casting string values to varchar?? When I insert that parameter into the pd.read_sql, the data.columns and data.dtypes parameters in the def updateType become unresolved attributes (when I hover over them in pycharm)

Comment: Shouldn't your "for" statement within the function def be referring to the parameter name data_para instead?

Comment: I would liaise with the people working with Teradata, and ask them to use FastExport to export the result of `SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 FROM HostServerName.Table1 WHERE Column3 IS NOT NULL` to a CSV file, with Comma (`','`) as the delimiter and enclosed by double quote (`'"'`). Then, once you have your `/data/some/dir/example.csv` file from them, connect to Vertica using either DBeaver, DbVisualizer or SQuirrel - or, for that matter, Vertica's `vsql`, run this command:  `COPY VerticaUSERDB.Table2 FROM '/data/some/dir/example.csv' DELIMITER ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';`

Comment: A Python Script will never be performant enough for big data volumes.